# Magento: Main store about link need to add in child store

Tags: magento

I have magento store joandjax.com and I have made one store name shop and url is shop.joandjax.com. Now I what in shop store about link from main store.

Means I want about page link in footer of joandjax.com (link : joandjax.com/about) to shop.joandjax.com (need like joandjax.com/about instead of shop.joandjax.com/about)

please check in mobile version (link in footer)

url generate using xml code like:

AboutaboutAbouttrue

Its always take store url instead of main store url